# Converting method signatures

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, casting, type-conversion

typedef void (__thiscall* LPVOIDPROC) (void);

```
class ClassA
{
  LPVOIDPROC m_pProc;

  void SetProc(LPVOIDPROC pProc)  { m_pProc = pProc; }

  void OnSomeEvent() { m_pProc(); }
}

class ClassB
{
  ClassA* pCA;

  void Proc() { /* ... */ }

  void Init()
  {
    // Assume pCA != NULL
    pCA->Set((LPVOIDPROC)&ClassB::Proc); // error C2440
  }
}
```

How to get rid of this error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall ClassB::* )(void)' to 'LPVOIDPROC' ? I don't want to limit LPVOIDPROC signature to ClassB only. This should be any class and referenced proc should not be static.

Comment: Uf the method is not static - how are you passing the class instance into ClassA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround:

```
typedef void (* CLASSPROC) (void *); 

template<class T, void (T::*proc)()>
void class_proc(void * ptr) 
{
 (static_cast<T*>(ptr)->*proc)();
}

class ClassA 
{ 
 CLASSPROC m_pProc;
 void    * m_pInstance;

public:
 void SetProc(void *pInstance, CLASSPROC pProc)  { 
          m_pInstance = pInstance; 
          m_pProc = pProc; 
     } 

 void OnSomeEvent() { m_pProc(m_pInstance); } 
};

class ClassB 
{ 
 ClassA* pCA; 

 void Proc() { /* ... */ } 

 void Init() 
 { 
  // Assume pCA != NULL 
  pCA->SetProc(this, class_proc<ClassB, &ClassB::Proc>);      
 } 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I refer you to this [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1). Your type `LPVOIDPROC` is a *pointer-to-function*, which is not the same thing as a *pointer-to-member-function*. When you try to cast `ClassB::Proc`, you are trying to convert a *pointer-to-member-function*, an invalid operation.

You should take a look at `boost::function`, that offers exactly what you are looking for. Or you could use functors to encapsulate your functions if you don't want to resort to boost. Example:

```
struct VoidProcFunctor {
    virtual void call() = 0;
};

class ClassB;
struct BProcFunctor : VoidProcFunctor {
    BProcFunctor(ClassB* b) : b_(b) {}
    void call();
private:
    ClassB* b_;        
}

class ClassA
{
public:
    VoidProcFunctor* m_pProc;

    void SetProc(VoidProcFunctor* pProc)  { m_pProc = pProc; }

    void OnSomeEvent() { m_pProc->call(); }
};

class ClassB
{
    ClassA* pCA;

    void Proc() { /* ... */ }

    void Init()
    {
        // Assume pCA != NULL
        // warning! this is not the best design possible
        BProcFunctor* bproc = new BProcFunctor(this);
        pCA->SetProc(bproc);
    }
};

void BProcFunctor::call() { b_->proc() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-static methods require a 'this' pointer, without a 'this' pointer you cannot call it, and so it makes no sense to cast it to a C function pointer.

Consider making a simple class (let's call it X) that has

- a data member that refers to a ClassB instance
- a () operator (although I prefer methods with clear names) calling ClassB::Proc using the ClassB instance as this-pointer.

Instead of passing a function pointer to class A, make an instance of X (with its datamember to ClassB filled in) and pass this to class A.
Instead of calling a function pointer class A should call x().

Class X could even be written using templates, so if you have this situation for more than one class you must only write it once.

I think that in C# it can be done cleaner using delegates but I leave that to the C# and .Net specialists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never cast function pointers.  You can end up with stack corruption.  Don't do it.
2. Don't pass pointers to non-static member functions.  They use a different calling convention and are not compatible.
3. In your case, making "Proc()" static might solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need your `Proc` method to be a static method.

Comment: OP says *This should be any class and referenced proc should **not be static**.*